# sub string replacment in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like:
$string = "/physics/mechanics/vectors/P-M-C (1).doc";

I want to get like this:

"/physics/mechanics/vectors/1-P-M-C (1).doc";

Please note that "1-" is added just before P in the original string.

Is it possible in PHP?
How the function in PHP should be used?

Comment: Are you always adding 1- to the file name?  Or does that correspond to the number in the parenthesis?  Are got strings always paths like your example?

Comment: If you describe the root problem you are trying to address then somebody might be able to answer you. But currently it is not clear what your issue is and a correct answer to your current question would be: echo '/physics/mechanics/vectors/1-P-M-C (1).doc'; as you haven't described what if any parts you want variable and what parts you want to match against.

Comment: Sorry if i have misinterpreted my problem wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fawad:Here's a sample to get you started --

```
$oldstring = "/physics/mechanics/vectors/P-M-C (1).doc";
$parts = explode("/", $oldstring);
$file = $parts[count($parts) - 1];

$newstring = str_replace($file, "1-" . $file, $oldstring);
```

Comment: This is the best general solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `explode()` and `join()` for this. :)

Comment: If you use `explode()` it makes sense to use `implode()` to do the inverse, even though its just an alias of `join()`.

Comment: Good that you point that out. I guess I'm too used to Python. :)

Comment: Thanks for giving time to this problem but i think "stealthyninja" has posted the best solution.